# How to sum <input>s that have the same <select> options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sum, subtotal

The thing is I have this form for multiple donation entrances, I'm almost done with it, I just need to calculate the subtotals of my donations. Basically every entry has an input and a select with 5 options - each of these options will serve as a subtotal for my donation inputs. I want to sum the donations that are in the same subtotal categories (same select options) and list them.

I'm having a lot of trouble coming up with a solution. Right now I'm looking for a solution either in vanilla js or jquery. Does anybody know how to do it?

Here's the HTML simplified:

```
 <label>donation value</label>
 <input type="number" class="donation">

 <select class="categories">
   <option id="cat1">category 1</option>
   <option id="cat2">category 2</option>
   <option id="cat3">category 3</option>
 </select>
```

EDIT: I would prefer if it was made with an onClick event. Thanks in advance!

Comment: To make sure I understand: The HTML structure above repeats? And each instance has a category and a value? And you want to subtotal by category?

Comment: It doesn't need to repeat because I already took care of that but I don't mind if yours do. Pretty much, I create an instance whenever I need of one, and each of them has a category and a input text for the value, yes. Exactly, subtotal by category. I forgot to include: I would prefer if it was by an onClick event, given my limited experience, it would be easier to track the event and to manage it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add onchange listeners to the inputs and update a data structure to track the values of each instance, then compute the subtotals from that data structure. This demo needs a little tuning--it doesn't handle clearing the amount field, for example--but it shows the basic idea:

```js
// an array to keep track of each donation instance
const donations = [];

// change handler for both the number input and the category select
// The first argument is the change event, from which we
// extract the target's name and value, where 'name' will be
// either 'category' for the select or 'amount' for the number input
function onDonationChange({target: {name, value}}, index) {
  // update the entry at [index] to reflect the change
  donations[index] = {
    // keep the existing fields for this entry if it exists,
    // otherwise create it using default values
    ...(donations[index] ?? { category: 'category 1', amount: 0}),
    // update with the event target's field name and value
    [name]: value
  };
  
  // update the subtotal display to reflect the change
  updateSubtotal();
}

function updateSubtotal () {
  // find the subtotal dom element we want to update
  const elem = document.querySelector('.subtotal');
  
  // compute the subtotals for each category, e.g.
  // { 'category 1': 100, 'category 2': 200 } etc.
  const subtotals = donations.reduce((acc, {category, amount}) => ({ ...acc, [category]: ((acc[category] ?? 0) + parseFloat(amount)) }), {});
  
  // update the display.
  // for each entry in subtotals, create an html snippet,
  // then join them into a single string.
  elem.innerHTML = Object.entries(subtotals)
    .map(([category, subtotal]) => (
      `<div><span class="cat">${category}</span>: ${subtotal}</div>`
    )).join('');
}

// find the items so we can add the event listeners
const items = document.querySelectorAll('li');

// iterate over each item and...
items.forEach((item, index) => {
  // find the input and select for this instance
  const inputs = item.querySelectorAll('input, select');
  
  // add a change listener that passes both the change
  // event and the item's index
  inputs.forEach(i => i.addEventListener('change', e => onDonationChange(e, index)));
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.cat {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <label>donation value</label>
    <input name="amount" type="number" class="donation">

    <select name="category" class="categories">
      <option>category 1</option>
      <option>category 2</option>
      <option>category 3</option>
    </select>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>donation value</label>
    <input name="amount" type="number" class="donation">

    <select name="category" class="categories">
      <option>category 1</option>
      <option>category 2</option>
      <option>category 3</option>
    </select>
  </li>

  <li>
    <label>donation value</label>
    <input name="amount" type="number" class="donation">

    <select name="category" class="categories">
      <option>category 1</option>
      <option>category 2</option>
      <option>category 3</option>
    </select>
  </li>

  <li>
    <label>donation value</label>
    <input name="amount" type="number" class="donation">

    <select name="category" class="categories">
      <option>category 1</option>
      <option>category 2</option>
      <option>category 3</option>
    </select>
  </li>

  <li>
    <label>donation value</label>
    <input name="amount" type="number" class="donation">

    <select name="category" class="categories">
      <option>category 1</option>
      <option>category 2</option>
      <option>category 3</option>
    </select>
  </li>

</ul>
<hr />
<div class="subtotal"></div>
```

---

Or if you really need to trigger it all at once after the fact:

```js
// Get a donation object for the given LI
// returns an object representing the LI's inputs, e.g.
// { category: 'category 1', amount: 122 }
function getDonation (listItem) {
  // find all the inputs and selects in this LI
  const inputs = listItem.querySelectorAll('input, select');
  
  // construct and return the object based on the inputs' names and values
  return [...inputs]
    .reduce((acc, {name, type, value}) => ({...acc, [name]: type === 'number' ? parseFloat(value) : value}), {})
}


function updateSubtotal() {
  // Get all of the LI's
  const listItems = document.querySelectorAll('li');
  
  // Get a donation object for each LI
  // Filter out items where amount is not a number
  const donations = [...listItems].map(getDonation).filter(({amount}) => !isNaN(amount));
  
  // Compute the subtotals for each category
  const subtotals = donations.reduce((acc, {category, amount}) => ({ ...acc, [category]: ((acc[category] ?? 0) + parseFloat(amount)) }), {});
  
  // Find the subtotal display element
  const displayElem = document.querySelector('.subtotal');
  
  // Generate and insert HTML from the computed subtotals
  displayElem.innerHTML = Object.entries(subtotals)
    .map(([category, amount]) => (
      `<div><span class="category">${category}</span>: <span class="amount">${amount}</span></div>`
    )).join('');
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.category {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.amount {
  color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <label>donation value</label>
    <input name="amount" type="number" class="donation">

    <select name="category" class="categories">
      <option>category 1</option>
      <option>category 2</option>
      <option>category 3</option>
    </select>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>donation value</label>
    <input name="amount" type="number" class="donation">

    <select name="category" class="categories">
      <option>category 1</option>
      <option>category 2</option>
      <option>category 3</option>
    </select>
  </li>

  <li>
    <label>donation value</label>
    <input name="amount" type="number" class="donation">

    <select name="category" class="categories">
      <option>category 1</option>
      <option>category 2</option>
      <option>category 3</option>
    </select>
  </li>

  <li>
    <label>donation value</label>
    <input name="amount" type="number" class="donation">

    <select name="category" class="categories">
      <option>category 1</option>
      <option>category 2</option>
      <option>category 3</option>
    </select>
  </li>

  <li>
    <label>donation value</label>
    <input name="amount" type="number" class="donation">

    <select name="category" class="categories">
      <option>category 1</option>
      <option>category 2</option>
      <option>category 3</option>
    </select>
  </li>
</ul>
<button onclick="updateSubtotal()">Update Subtotal</button>
<hr />
<div class="subtotal"></div>
```

Comment: I like your code very much, thanks a lot. Can you make it fit my last requirement? I'm trying your code here but having a little trouble with the event onChange.

Comment: What is your last requirement?

Comment: Instead of an onChange event use an onClick event. I tried but didn't have much luck. Is it possible?

Comment: Man your code is very good. I'm having problems though. It's probably my fault but I wasn't able to make the subtotals work when I try it with my code, maybe it's due to the fact I'm creating each instance dinamically. I tried your code without creating any of my instances dinamically and it worked just fine. I'm definitely accepting your answer. Could you help me solve this issue though? 

[My demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kai98/kqy10oaz/8/)

Comment: The issue with subtotals on your demo is that when you create a new donation you're giving the number input a unique name (e.g. `amount_1`). The subtotal function is adding up the `'amount'` fields so it's ignoring the new inputs. If you take out the line that adds the name suffix (line 28) [it works](https://jsfiddle.net/rayhatfield/m6bjgwtk/).

Comment: It could be tweaked to handle the unique names if that's something you need, but the way it's currently written it's looking for "amount" explicitly.

Comment: Jesus mate, you saved me. I was pretty lost, couldn't find any solutions. Thanks a lot for you time and patience, really.

Comment: Happy to help.

Comment: About the unique names, it's possible that - with your solution - I won't be needing them anymore. Thanks again.